# Different links in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am using MediaWiki version 1.18.2, I know that if I want my links to open in new tab/window I have to set up

```
$wgExternalLinkTarget = '_blank';
```

in LocalSettings.php

I am creating the links like this

```
[http://www.google.com/ google]
```

is there a way that I can make some links open in the same tab/window and others in new tab/window with the same settings in LocalSettings.php?

Comment: Not that I know. By what syntax would you want to distinguish your link types?

Comment: I like to use for example '[http://www.google.com/ google]
 and [http://www.google.com|target='_blank' google]
' so the first opens in same and second link opens in new window.

Comment: Uh, a pipe ("|") breaks the parser's link recognition. That will need a deep hack, I fear.

Comment: It does not have to be "|" pipe, that was just an example, but some way that I can put links that open and links that are not opening new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediawiki allows you to wrap html  tags around links; you can set the default to not open a new tab/window, and for those you do want to have in a new window, wrap in a different class:

```
<span class="new-win">[http://google.com google]</span>
```

Then you can use JavaScript to make all the "new-win"-wrapped links open a new window; add this to your Common.js script:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) { 
  $(".new-win a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Keep from following standard href of link
    new_win = window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'offsite_popup') // Pop up a window to that URL
    if (window.focus) { new_win.focus() } // Give it focus if possible
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** Modified for user's intent

Comment: Why to use that when I can use this: $wgExternalLinkTarget = '_blank'; as I understand you it will do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily write an extension doing that by using the [LinkerMakeExternalLink](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/LinkerMakeExternalLink) hook.

Comment: Yes, but that will be for all links, and I want to have different links.

Comment: Your hook would get to decide what to do with each link.